# DataContract + IxmlSerializable

Tags: c#, serialization, linq-to-xml, datacontract, ixmlserializable

We have a project with "custom objects and attributes" created on a java server, and need this data on a C# client.

e.g. Custom object 'A' has attributes 'B', 'C'. Both 'B' and 'C' are described by customer in run time. Server sends this to us in XML like:

```
<A>
    <B> B Data </B>
    <C> C Data </C>
</A>
```

We created a class implementing **IXmlSerializable** that reads/writes xml for server filling the custom attributes to a dictionary

```
public class CustomObject : IXmlSerializable
{
    private Dictionary<String, String> attributes;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        attributes = XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadOuterXml()).Root.Elements()
            .ToDictionary(xElm => xElm.Name.LocalName, xElm => xElm.Value)
    }

    // More Serialization logic for IXmlSerializable is here
}
```

The project is slow and we want to use the faster DataContract Serialization.
We tested on a sample by explicitly specifying hard coded [DataContract] on our attributes (like 'B', 'C'). However in our use case attributes are not known at compile time. We can query server for list of attributes on type 'A'.

How can we use DataContract for attributes defined at runtime

Comment: You could try implementing [`IExtensibleDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx) on your `CustomObject`, then extracting the XML using the trick in [ExtensionDataObject not marked as serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056762).  But, have you profiled to determine where the real problem is?

Comment: Why do you do `XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadOuterXml())`?  That effectively parses the XML twice.  If you're having problems with performance, you could replace that with [`ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @dbc, it seems XDocument is taking around 16 ms for every object and also adds to our memory signature. That is why we want DataContract. I will check the link you have shared.

Comment: @dbc there is more logic in the function. I just reduced it for demo. Will ReadSubtree() provide XElement ? XElement is required for further logic that is part of our project

Comment: Actually `XNode.ReadFrom()` would be better.  Answer updated.

Comment: Testing your solution @dbc

Answer (score 1):

Explicit data contracts that allow for arbitrary, unknown elements are not supported by `DataContractSerializer`.  `XmlSerializer` supports this via [`[XmlAnyElementAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx), but as stated in the answer [Using [XmlAnyElement]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520228/using-xmlanyelement), there is no identical functionality for data contracts.

Your class could implement [`IExtensibleDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx).  It is similar to `[XmlAnyElement]` and is intended for [forward-compatible data contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx).  Unfortunately, in that case the unknown elements are stored in an opaque [`ExtensionDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject.aspx) with no obvious way to access the values.  While it is possible to extract the XML from such an object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056762/extensiondataobject-not-marked-as-serializable)) it's nonobvious and is unlikely to be more performant than your current code, as it requires re-serializing the `ExtensionDataObject` inside a wrapper class, then parsing the result.

One note about performance - when you do `XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadOuterXml())`, the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,2e70466b502f4206) shows you are effectively parsing your XML, then streaming it through an `XmlWriter` to a `StringWriter`, then parsing the resulting string a second time.  Rather than doing this, you can parse the XML only once by calling [`XNode.ReadFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx) on the incoming reader, like so:

```
public class CustomObject : IXmlSerializable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<String, String> attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public IDictionary<string, string> Attributes { get { return attributes; } }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var element = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in element.Elements())
                attributes.Add(item.Name.LocalName, (string)item);
        }
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Do NOT write the wrapper element when writing.
        foreach (var pair in attributes)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This should be more performant than your current class.  For instance, in [Web API performance issues with large dynamic XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993958/web-api-performance-issues-with-large-dynamic-xml/28994996#28994996) the reported improvement for a similar optimization was 40%.

**Update**

For the best possible performance implementing `IXmlSerializable` you will need to read content directly from the `XmlReader` using bespoke code.  The following, for instance, reads element names and values into the `attributes` dictionary:

```
    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }
        reader.Read();
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    var key = reader.Name;
                    var value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    attributes.Add(key, value);
                    break;

                default:
                    // Comment, for instance.
                    reader.Read();
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Consume the EndElement
        reader.Read();
    }
```

See [Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) for some general guidelines on manually reading an element hierarchy correctly.

Comment: Tried this, I find your solution a valid performance issue, but it did not add a significant change, so we still need a better solution. ExtensionDataObject wont help either as we do need access to data from the custom attributes.

Comment: @KitiAzura - the most performant way to parse the XML then will be to do it manually.  From [Chapter 9 — Improving XML Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx): *If you want to read the document once, use [XmlReader]. This provides forward-only, read-only, and non-cached access to XML data. This model provides optimized performance and memory conservation.*  Also see [Effective Xml Part 1: Choose the right API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2011/09/14/effective-xml-part-1-choose-the-right-api/).

Comment: I think your above comment looks like the correct answer. At lease this is what I wanted to do, before we came across DataContract.

Comment: @KitiAzura - I added a bespoke version of `ReadXml()` that works directly with the `XmlReader`.  Beyond this you may need to profile and share more details about your measured performance bottlenecks.